# SVN Python API with TortoiseSVN

Tags: python, tortoisesvn, svn-api

To use the SVN API with a Python script is it enough to have TortoiseSVN installed or do I need another SVN client?

I am using the cmd line features of tortoiseSVN but I'm looking for more advanced possibilities to work with SVN and wonder if I need to install another SVN client or so..

Thanks, Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're going to shell out to run a command-line program from within Python, you should be using [PySvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) or the "[Subversion for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.8.5/)" distribution which includes Python libraries.

If you still want to run a command-line program from your Python script, use either the <kbd>svn.exe</kbd> that comes with the TortoiseSVN installation, or the one from the above-referenced Subversion for Windows. The TortoiseSVN command-line program (<kbd>TortoiseProc.exe</kbd>) is not intended to be used from within other scripts/programs like you describe.

Comment: Yes, I realised that with tortoise.. but PySvn gives me everything I need! Cheers, -M